# What is reason behind JBoss LiveReload being deprecated and is there any alternative?

Tags: jboss, deprecated, livereload

I am interested to know the reason behind LiveReload JBoss tool being deprecated. May I know the alternative for LiveReload as it got deprecated? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveReload JBoss tool was deprecated because of low development and maintenance of its source code.

It may be reverted if someone starts actively developing or maintaining its source code.

[Refer link for more details](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-25736?_sscc=t)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there any alternative for LiveReload JBoss tool that are in active development. Thanks!

Comment: You can try live.js or reloadr but I have not used them so not sure about it's effectiveness.